# For loop to get user input lets you enter two values for the first question, but only calculates one value

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner

I created a small program that asks the user for 10 random numbers and it will print the sum of those numbers. I embedded it with a for loop and included a counter. Everything seems to be working fine except when I run the program, the first question allows me to enter two values, but it will still only calculate a total of 10 numbers.

Below is what I currently have and I need to understand what is going wrong when it prompts the user for the number the first time:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Enter number #" + counter + " :");
            int numberInput = scanner.nextInt();
            boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
            if (hasNextInt) {
                sum += numberInput;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Number");
            }
        }
        scanner.nextLine(); // handle the next line character (enter key)
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check Answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop, you're calling `scanner.nextInt()` and `scanner.hasNextInt()`. But you do not use the result of `hasNextInt()` in a meaningful way (you might have noticed that your "Invalid Number" output is not what happens if you enter something that's not a number).

The first call to `nextInt()` blocks until you enter a number. Then `hasNextInt()` will block again because the number has already been read, and you're asking whether there will be a new one. This next number is read from `System.in`, but you're not actually using it in this iteration (you merely asked whether it's there). Then in the next iterations, `nextInt()` will not block because the scanner already pulled a number from `System.in` and can return it immediately, so all the subsequent prompts you see actually wait for input on `hasNextInt()`.

This amounts to 11 total input events: The firts `nextInt()` plus all 10 `hasNextInt()`s

Comment: So nextInt() shouldn't proceed hasNextInt() due to this? Does it need to be embedded in a while loop so the input can be validated with hasNextInt?

Comment: If you want to use `hasNextInt` for validation, it should always come before `nextInt`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Enter number #" + counter + " :");
        int numberInput = scanner.nextInt();
       // boolean hasNextInt = scanner.hasNextInt();
        //if (hasNextInt) {
            sum += numberInput;
      //  } else {
        //    System.out.println("Invalid Number");
        //}
    }
    scanner.nextLine(); // handle the next line character (enter key)
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
    scanner.close();
```

Don't call hasnextInt() it has no use here.

It has taken 11 inputs rather than 10.

If you remove this condition it will take 10 inputs and work fine.

Your condition have no impact on it.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I properly use hasNextInt for validation?

Comment: Glad to know, it has created ease in your way. What type of validation you required ? Do you want if any input typed other then int then it will validate ? Is this type of Validation ?